# How to have a Not Found Page WITHOUT the navigation bar

Tags: angular, navigation

I am working on routing and navigation but stuck on how to render the 404 page with out the nav and the page title.

app.copmponent.html

```
<h2>Bonsai Store Ap</h2>
<nav>
    <a class="button" routerLink="/products" routerLinkActive="activebutton" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Products</a> |
    <a class="button" routerLink="/cart" routerLinkActive="activebutton" aruaCurrentWhenActive="page">Shopping Cart</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductsListComponent } from './products-list/products-list.component';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'products', component: ProductsListComponent },
      { path: 'cart', component: ShoppingCartComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ]),
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductsListComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I wanted the page not found component to be rendered without the nav buttons and the page title

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer!! it's all about hierarchy in you're routing

app. component.html

home.component.html

```js
<h2>Bonsai Store App</h2>
<nav>
    <a class="button" routerLink="/products" routerLinkActive="activebutton" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Products</a> |
    <a class="button" routerLink="/cart" routerLinkActive="activebutton" aruaCurrentWhenActive="page">Shopping Cart</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```js
 RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
          path: '',
          component: HomeComponent,
          children: [
            { path: 'products', component: ProductsListComponent },
            { path: 'cart', component: ShoppingCartComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
          ]
        },
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
```